# Select all rows from table where entrie in col 1 AND col 2 are identic

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that contains a few columns with entries. In column 1 is the campaign name which can occur more than once (in the table). In column 2 is the order date. In column 3 is the number of successfull delivered mails of that campaign.

Now what I want to do: I want select all columns where the entry in column 1 is the same AND in column the entry in column 2 is the same (only one of them is not enough)

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2           ||col3|
+--------------------------------+---------------+------
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||2017-01-01     ||15 |
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  ||2016-12-12     ||10 |
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||2017-01-01     ||10 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||2017-02-11     ||1  |
|20170117_SV_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE ||2017-02-03     ||25 |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE           ||2017-01-29     ||9  |
```

I want a query that will select:

```
|col1                           ||col2           ||col3|
+--------------------------------+---------------+------
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||2017-01-01     ||15 |
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE         ||2017-01-01     ||10 |
```

This what I got so far:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TableA T1 JOIN 
(
    SELECT col1
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND col2=col2
) T2
ON T1.col1 = T2.col1;
```

-> But this is not working correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also `GROUP BY` the date:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM TableA T1 
JOIN ( SELECT col1 
       FROM TableA 
       GROUP BY col1, col2 
       HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 ) T2 ON T1.col1 = T2.col1;
```